# Pandas.to_datetime when dates are 9999-01-01

Tags: python, sql, pandas, datetime

I have read an SQL table into pandas, and now I want to convert the dates from strings into the pandas datetime type. The problem is, however, that SQL has a maximum date of "9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999", while Pandas has a maximum date somewhere in 2262.

So I could do the following, which is extremely slow:

```
def safe_convert(date):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(date)
    except OutOfBoundsDatetime:
        return pd.Timestamp('2262-04-11')

df['start_date'] = df['start_date'].apply(safe_convert)
```

A faster alternative is the following, which however results in pd.NaTs:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], errors='coerce')
```

Is there not a way to achieve the first, just in a performant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using your second option and filling the NaTs?

```
df['start_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], errors='coerce')
                      .fillna(pd.Timestamp('2262-04-11'))
                   )
```

Or, if you originally have NaTs/NaNs and don't want to fill those:

```
df['start_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], errors='coerce')
                      .mask(lambda x: x.isna() & df['start_date'].notna(),
                            pd.Timestamp('2262-04-11'))
                   )
```